# Xcode publish with more compatibility?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

When I publish to testflight I find there are problems with users who haven't updated to the latest iOS version.  This was especially conspicuous during this past series of iWatch updates.

Is there a simple way to set the compatibility before creating an archive?

I tried googling this but alas it was not amenable to my google-fu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can set the compatibility by changing the "Deployment Target" in Project > Info**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click your target, in General pane, set the Deployment Target minimal version.